# Rails 3, make submit call specific function in controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, submit

new to web development, here.  I have a form like this:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm"  method="post" >

      <select id="id" name="foo">
        ...some stuff
      </select>

      <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

The submit button calls the 'index' method of my controller, as expected.  I would like to make it call some other function, such as 'update', how do I do that?  I need to do something with the @_params hash, but I don't want invoke the index function, to do it.  Thanks.

Comment: You should include the view code to generate the above HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include the view logic so I am going to take a stab in the dark and guess you are writing the HTML for the form rather than using the RoR helpers.

In rails there are a set of helpers that help you generate forms and form items.

Please check the docs for [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Using form_for will follow the basic restful routing unless you modify the url parameter.  So if you are on /new you will be routed to /create, if you are on /edit, you will be routed to /update.  More precisely, if the object is new, you will submit to create, if the model exists you will submit to update.

If your form doesn't use a model, you can use the [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) helper that takes a url parameter and you can pass a string specifying what path to submit to.

If you just need to know how to do this in plain HTML, read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).  Essentially, you need to include an action attribute on form that specifies the path to the action you want to post to.